# MySQL Stored Proc returning NULL values when i call the 2 OUT parameters - see code

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysqlimport

I am studying for the mysql certification and the way i learn is by doing, I failed it before by one question and if i had of paid more attention to stored procs i would have gotten it. any i am making up some funky scenarios that i would actually use so here is one that i am stumped on.

```
    /*TABLE STRUCTURE */
    CREATE TABLE `members` (
      `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );


    /* PROCEDURE STRUCTURE */
    USE WOL_STATISTICS;

    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `select_user`
    (
    IN `idnum` INT(11),
    OUT `name` VARCHAR(255),
    OUT `email` VARCHAR(255)
    )

    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC


    BEGIN
    SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `members` WHERE `id` = `idnum`;
    END $$

    DELIMITER ;


    /* CALL STATEMENT */

    CALL select_user(20, @name, @email);
        SELECT @name, @email;
```

I keep getting back null values can anyone tell me why??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure your table definition is correct? You seem to have to columns named `id` in your table.

Second: You're selecting the `name` and `email` columns from the table, but you're not assigning the values to the out parameters `name` and `email` (maybe you should rename the parameters to something else to avoid such mixups, like `outname` and `outemail`). This is not done automatically. There's a huge difference between telling the `SELECT` statement explicitly which columns to select and assigning the results to variables.

So while the stored procedure actually returns a result set, the two out parameters will always be `null` unless you assign values to them.

Comment: Hi sorry about that i actually removed the 2nd id when i created the table i am testing on, it was a mistake. I am still lost. I have renamed the out parameters to   OUT `outname` VARCHAR(255),
    OUT `outemail` VARCHAR(255) and i am trying to obtain their results using the following CALL select_user(20, '@outname', '@outemail');
SELECT '@outname', '@outemail'; but still gettin null

Comment: Like Thorsten said, assign values to your variables. Do `SELECT name, email INTO outname, outemail FROM ...` (if I remember the syntax correctly).

Answer (score 0):

change your from:
SELECT `name`, `email` FROM `members` WHERE `id` = `idnum`;
to
SELECT `name`, `email` INTO PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_EMAIL FROM `members` WHERE `id` = `idnum`;

Try use another paramter name like P_NAME, P_EMAIL e set like that:

SELECT `name`, `email` INTO P_NAME, P_EMAIL FROM `members` WHERE `id` = P_IDNUM;